# Expression Engine using the Champagne Extension troubleshooting

Tags: email, rest, expressionengine

I have an issue in Expression Engine using the Champagne Extension where it won't allow me to send out campaigns. This extension utilizes https://www.campaignmonitor.com/ api to send out mass emails.

The Error I get is "HTML Content URL Required" when I try to send out campaigns form the back end of the Expression Engine Install.

What could be causing this issue that relates to the expression engine install?

Comment: I wold suggest contacting the author of the Champagne extension for support. http://natural-logic.com/software/support/

Comment: not much of a support team :/

Comment: WOW.. .htaccess password was preventing that

Answer (score 1):

This error is received anytime the URL to your `html` or text content is not visible. More often this is seen when someone forget to include the text version. A good way to test is to click the preview HTML/TEXT button and make sure both give you the correct results.

They cannot be blank.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative solution, be sure to checkout my add-on Postmaster. It allows clients to publish email campaigns just by creating a new entry. You can setup any number of configuration, so you can even send draft email to a test subscriber list. And since everything is within channel entries, you can use whatever fieldtypes you like, and it works with MailChimp as well as CampaignMonitor.

https://objectivehtml.com/articles/postmaster-the-definitive-email-solution-for-expressionengine

Comment: OP is asking about a specific error with a specific extension; suggesting for them to change to using your own library doesn't feel like an appropriate answer to that.